# Remove duplicates in sorted linked list-code not working.What is the error?

Tags: linked-list

Remove duplicates in sorted linked list-code not working.What is the error?

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * struct ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     ListNode *next;
 *     ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(NULL) {}
 * };
 */
class Solution {
public:
    ListNode* deleteDuplicates(ListNode* head) {
        if(head==NULL || head->next==NULL)return head;
        ListNode* curr=head;
        while(curr!=NULL)
        {
            while(curr->val==curr->next->val){
                curr->next=curr->next->next;
            }
            curr=curr->next;    
        }
        return head;
    }
};
```

http://notes.io/qs1p

Comment: I reverted your edit because you removed the code from the question, making it difficult for anyone to help you.

Comment: ok.i thought of sharing the link.

Comment: Nothing at all wrong with the link, but please include the code as well :-)

Comment: alright.got it.thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a problem with the logic which removes duplicates.  Change your `while` loop to this:

```
    while (curr != NULL) {
        ListNode* index = curr;
        while (curr->val == index->next->val) {  // check for multiple possible duplicates
            index = index->next;                 // and advance index to last duplicate
        }
        curr->next = index->next;                // splice out the duplicate (if it exists)
        curr = curr->next;                       // advance pointer
    }
```

Comment: thanks.I understand your logic.I tried similar to your technique.Can you tell me where I am going wrong in my code so that I can improve my code.

Comment: In your original code, you were missing the logic to splice out the duplicates.  Instead, you just assigned the `curr` next value to be its next value, which leaves your list in the same state.

Comment: doesn´t the inner while loop take care of splicing the duplicates

Comment: The inner `while` loop simply finds the next element in the list which you want to _keep_.  It is up to the outer `while` loop to iterate over the entire list.